# How to stop timer after X seconds/clicks

Tags: vb.net, browser, refresh

I have an application that automatically clicks on a button for me about 1 time every second depending on the speed I choose. However, it times out so I need to add a refresh to this page. I need to stop my `timer1` after so many clicks and have a `WebBrowser1.Refresh()`,  then once the refresh is done, `timer1` kicks in with the clicks and the process is done all over again. I have no idea how to start this because I haven't ever had to stop a timer before, but I've been reading up on it and it looks relatively easy. Here is the script I'm working with:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 40
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 100
    Else
        Timer1.Interval = 500
    End If

    If ((WebBrowser1.IsBusy)) Then



    Else
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)


        Timer1.Start()


    End If


End Sub
```

As you can see, once the button is clicked once it does `Timer1.Start()` over and over again, and in `Timer1.start()`'s code you can see the code to click once:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
```

Which it works, but I need to stop my `Timer1` after so many clicks/seconds and have a refresh web browser in. I have no idea how to start this, and if anyone could lead me in the right tracks I'd be thankful. (Sorry for bad grammar/run on sentences, I'm new to English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, but not necessarily the "cleanest" way is to have a public integer variable declared.

I.e.

```
Public Class Form1
'Public variables are decleared here
Dim number_of_ticks as integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

On the Timer_Tick event, you simply add 1 to the number_of_ticks variable.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Not number_of_ticks > 100 Then
'[EDIT:] I forgot to increase the number_of_ticks
    number_of_ticks += 1
        'put your code here
    Else
        'number_of_ticks has exceed the maximum amount of allowed ticks
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

**[EDIT:]
The number_of_ticks += 1 increases the variable once every time the code is run.
Once again, I apologize for my mistake.**

To limit the amount of ticks allowed, simply increase / decrease the number_of_ticks variable.
If your timer interval is 500ms then the Timer_Tick event will be raised two times a second, therefore after one second - the number_of_ticks will be 2.
If you want the timer to run for 10 seconds, set the number_of_ticks to 20.

If this doesn't help, please question my answer.

Good Luck!

Comment: Well I thought it would work but it didn't. No matter what I do the Timer1 never stops with your script, but it will stop without your script. For a large example, I have posted here (Since I can't post all of it on here): http://pastebin.com/YeU9BBq9 As you can see with your whole code in, no matter what I set the variable on "If Not number_of_ticks > 20 Then", it just keeps autoclicking as if it is ignoring the else function to "Timer1.Enabled = False" (stop autoclicking).

Comment: I'm so sorry, @Jack C.! I have forgot a really important piece of the script, please check again above - **I have edited it!**

Comment: Wow! It worked! Thank you ALOT Alex. I have been struggling with this code for a while now, I'm glad someone can pull through and help me. No need to say sorry :)

Comment: No worries, @Jack C.! I can tell you're not too familiar with vb.net, so I thought I could help you - everything's a bit harsh at first :)
If you ever need help again, remember me ;)

Comment: Thanks man! And yes I'm fairly new to VB, I have been doing PHP for a while but not a lot of VB. Also I have one last question, do you know how I can clear the variable number_of_ticks, such as reset it to 0?

Comment: Well I am actually trying to do some PHP right now ;)
How much PHP do you know? Enough to debug a small amount of code that I have?

To "reset" the variable, like before you start the timer again you use:

number_of_ticks = 0

Put that code after the "Timer1.stop" code

Comment: Well I used to know a lot of PHP, I coded my entire forum in it. I guess it depends on the code you have. If I could contact you through the chat I would but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: I got it to work, I had mixed up a " with two ''
Sometimes things are just too frustrating.

I will try to give you some rep by upvoting your post! Accept my answer to give me some too, if you want to :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code. First of all you don't appear to be using `Timer_Tick` or `Timer_Elapsed` event anywhere (I don't know which Timer are you using; there are multiple timer classes in .NET Framework), which is the ACTUAL event that would be fired upon interval completion. Secondly, Timer can be enabled/disabled simply by settings its `Enabled` property, which you're not doing anywhere. You should also take a look at how `Enabled` property works in conjunction with `Interval` property to make sure it behaves exactly as you expect.

Comment: Well yes I know I can do Timer1.enabled = True or I can do to Timer1.start() I just felt the second was easier. This really doesn't help me though.